# Prove $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)} \sqrt{(x − y)} \ln |x + y| = 0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am asked to prove that the limit of this multivariable function is equal to zero. I used the squeeze theorem to say that the limit is greater than 0 and less than x+y, by taking the limit of those we get that it is between zero and zero thus making it = to 0.

Comment: Did you mean to write $\sqrt{|x-y|}$ by any chance, or perhaps the "one-sided" limit where both $x$ and $y$ approach $0$ from the "right"?

Comment: As stated, we need $x\ge y,x+y\ne 0.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit is not $0$ and in fact does not exist.

- If the limit is taken along the line $x=y$, then the limit is trivially $0$.
- However, if the limit is approached along the path described parametrically by $x(t)=t$ and $y(t)=-t+e^{-1/t}$, then the limit becomes

$$\begin{align}\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\sqrt{|x-y|}\log|x+y|&=-\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{|2t-e^{-1/t}|}}{t}\\\\&=-\infty\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

There may be some lack of rigor in this, but still.

$$\sqrt{x-y}\log(|x+y|) = \log\left(|x+y|^{\sqrt{x-y}}\right)$$

Since $x\to 0$ and $y\to 0$ we can say either $(x+y)\to 0$ and $(x-y)\to 0$.

Now we know that

$$\lim_{z\to 0}\ z^z = 1$$

And also

$$\lim_{z\to 0}\ z^{\sqrt{z}} = 1$$
and so

$$\log\left(|x+y|^{\sqrt{x-y}}\right) = \log(1) = 0$$

The lack of rigor consists in the fact that actually we may have $x-y = i\epsilon$ for $|\epsilon| <<< 1$.

Comment: $|x+y| \neq \sqrt{x-y}$, show how can you use $\lim_{z \to 0} z^z=1$?

Comment: $$\lim_{x\to 0} x^{\sqrt{x}} = 1$$ holds again.

I assumed that $x+y$ and $x-y$ were about similar, but again: the problem that could arise is written in the end of the answer

Comment: But in that case $|x+ y| \neq x-y$.

Comment: That is true @Hetebrij Indeed I played a bit, it may have been useful somehow.